# Xamarin Android SDK adb.exe does not exist

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk, adb

So i just downloaded the vstoolsforxamarin fro mthe xamarin website. For some reason I do not have the platform-tools folder or the adb.exe . Without this I can't work with any android project. What can I do?

**Update:**

I found the solution. I opened the Android SDK Manager outside the VS and I Installed the abd.exe from it. Then I got the folder I needed and it is solved. Thanks :)

Comment: What locations have you looked for the platform-tools folder?

Answer (score 2):

On windows the default location is :

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\
```

or on a Mac it is:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/
```

Answer (score 0):

Open sdk manager (with administrator rights) and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"